# dotnet restore getting error with new csproj file, no project.json file

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, yeoman-generator

I am starting to develop an ASP.NET Core MVC Web application with yeoman
generated project and ran `dotnet restore`.

It gives me this error:

> The folder '/home/hemal/DOTNET/MyFirstApp' does not contain a project to restore.

There is no `project.json` file but new `MyFirstApp.csproj` file is there.

How can resolve this?

Comment: what is your dotnet -version? Which template you choose from yeoman generator?

Comment: Dotnet 1.1.0 latest one. I also have new csproj file. Web application without authentication in yeoman.

Comment: check that version is correct if you run `dotnet -version` from root project folder, as it may be overridden by `global.json` file.

Comment: OK then what should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this on my Mac too. The problem is that the Yeoman generator (generator-aspnet) has already been upgraded to use the new .csproj project system, which will fail if you have an older version of `dotnet` installed.

If the output of `dotnet --version` on your machine is lower than `1.0.0-rc3-004530`, that's the source of the error. Install the latest version and try again, it should work fine.

I was able to get it working with the [RC3 release](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/rc3-download.md) (or later) of the dotnet tooling. Note that at the time of writing (February 2017), the official .NET Core downloads page **does not** have the version you need!

Comment: I just installed both yeoman and dotnet on my Mac and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @AdamMendoza What is the output of `dotnet --version`?

Comment: I'm getting 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177   Just installed it.

Comment: @AdamMendoza That's the current "stable" release, but you'll need RC3 or later to work with csproj. See the link in my answer for the download.

Comment: Thanks. I'll install from link

Comment: I couldn't install RC3 on my Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: @Hemal If you got an error when installing, post another question or ask on GitHub?

Comment: Sure, I have submitted an issue on github. Please see if you can find an answer

Comment: I did found a working hack on github with this issue link https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/496. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the latest Yeoman generate need updated version of .NetCore because Yeoman generator creates .csproj file and the latest version support .csproj file. I had this issue on mac and installed latest version of .NetCore and it worked fine for me. You can get latest SKD from [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). I installed **macOS (x64) PKG**.